# How to implement Multiple site sub domain concept with common account module with zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, subdomain

How to implement following concept with zend framework?

Multiple site sub domain concept with common account module.

1.Site main URL:  http://www.maindomain.com

2.Multiple site common login URL: http://www.maindomain.com/account/signin

3.Site1 URL: travelstore.maindomain.com  OR http://www.maindomain.com/travelstore

4.Site2 URL: supermarket.maindoamin.com  OR http://www.maindomain.com/supermarket

(NOTE: Only session information between the domains is user id, so user doesn't have to login again in to other site mean in sub domain)

Comment: Set your subdomains up as controllers or modules and then use host routing to specify where the subdomains should go. There are plenty of examples around. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname

Answer (score 0):

you should use the modules for each subdomains and then play with the routes to make http://www.maindomain.com/travelstore in http://travelstore.maindomain.com!

Comment: Thanks Jelly... I am also thinking on this way... but i thinking that, is this best way to do this task?

Comment: I think that is the best way!